# DeepFace install on macOS M1- Error on tensor-flow dependency

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyinstaller, deepface

I use MacOS-12.5, M1 chip

I have successfully installed tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal. Below are version details

```
tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                        
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    
tensorflow-macos          2.9.2
```

I receive error when I install deepface

```
pip install deepface

Error:
 package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
    deepface 0.0.75 depends on tensorflow>=1.9.0
```

Any suggestions on installing deepface?

Comment: `tensorflow-macos` is not considered `tensorflow`, so the dependencies don't match. Try installing `deepface` without dependencies and dependency checking, `pip install --no-deps deepface`.

Comment: `pip install --no-deps deepface` download doesnt show any error but `from deepface import DeepFace` shows tensorflow error. Is it possible to download tensorflow (not tensorflow-macos) on Mac M1?